# Генетический алгоритм. Поиск экстремума функции

Tags: c++

Пишу алгоритм для поиска экстремума функции z = (x - 1)^4 - (y + 2)^4.
По логике вещей экстремум там, где скорость изменения z минимальна

соорудил такую фитнесс функцию

```
void fitness(int n)
{
    float speed,x,y,coeff=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x = generation[i][0] - 1;
        y = generation[i][1] + 2;
        if ((pow(x, 4) - pow(0.1, 4) != 0))
        {
            speed = abs((pow(x + 0.1, 4) - pow(y + 0.1, 4)) - (pow(x - 0.1, 4) - pow(y - 0.1, 4)));
            generation[i].push_back(speed);
        }
        else
        {
            generation[i].push_back(1000);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        coeff += 1 / generation[i][2];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        generation[i][2]=trunc(abs(1 / 1/generation[i][2] / coeff) * 1000) / 10;
    }
}
```

проблема в том, что когда программа натыкается на решение уравнения - скорость оказывается нулевой, хотя эта точка не является экстремумом.
как этого избежать? (костыль прикрученный мною не в счет)

вот весь код:

```
            // ConsoleApplication17.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
            //

            #include "stdafx.h"
            #include <iostream>
            #include <fstream>
            #include <string>
            #include <vector>
            #include <algorithm>
            #include <ctime>
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <fstream>
            #include <windows.h>

            using namespace std;
            int n,iter=0;
            float trigger;
            vector<vector<float>>generation(30);
            vector<int> rnarr;
            ofstream fin;

            void firstgen(int n)
            {
                srand(time(0));
                int num;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                    {
                        num = rand() % 1000 - 500;
                        generation[i].push_back(num);
                    }
                }
            }

            void output(int n,int n1)
            {
                cout << "iter #" << iter << "\n";
                fin << "iter #" << iter << "\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++)
                    {
                        cout << generation[i][j] << " ";
                        fin << generation[i][j] << " ";
                    }
                    cout << "\n";
                    fin << "\n";
                }
                cout << "\n";
                fin<< "\n";
            }

            void fitness(int n)
            {
                float speed,x,y,coeff=0;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    x = generation[i][0] - 1;
                    y = generation[i][1] + 2;
                    if ((pow(x, 4) - pow(0.1, 4) != 0))
                    {
                        speed = abs((pow(x + 0.1, 4) - pow(y + 0.1, 4)) - (pow(x - 0.1, 4) - pow(y - 0.1, 4)));
                        generation[i].push_back(speed);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        generation[i].push_back(1000);
                    }
                    /*if (speed < 10)
                    {
                        cout << generation[i][0] << " " << generation[i][1] << " " << speed;
                        exit;
                    }*/
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    coeff += 1 / generation[i][2];
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    generation[i][2]=trunc(abs(1 / 1/generation[i][2] / coeff) * 1000) / 10;
                }
            }

            void sort(int n)
            {
                int max = 0, j = 0, flag = 0;;
                do
                {
                    for (int i = j; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        if (generation[i][2] > max)
                        {
                            max = generation[i][2];
                            flag = i;
                        }
                    }
                    swap(generation[flag], generation[j]);
                    j++;
                    flag = 0;
                    max = 0;
                } while (j < n);
            }

            void rng(int n)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < ceil(generation[i][2]); j++)
                    {
                        rnarr.push_back(i);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < rnarr.size(); i++)
                {
                    fin << rnarr[i];
                }
                fin << "\n";
            }

            void crossover(int n)
            {
                vector<vector<float>>next_gen(30);
                int point1,point2;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                        point1 = rnarr[rand() % rnarr.size()];
                        point2 = rnarr[rand() % rnarr.size()];
                        next_gen[i].push_back(generation[point1][rand() % 1]);
                        next_gen[i].push_back(generation[point2][rand() % 1]);
                }
                generation = next_gen;
            }

            void mutation(int n)
            {
                int flag;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    flag = rand() % 1000 - 500;
                    if (flag >= 0)
                    {
                        generation[i][rand() % 1] += rand() % 200 - 100;
                    }
                }
            }

            void antipushback(int n)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    generation[i].pop_back();
                }
            }

            void cleanup()
            {
                rnarr.clear();
                iter++;
            }

            int main()
            {
                fin.open("C:\\Users\\andrey\\Desktop\\1.txt");
                cin >> n;
                firstgen(n);
                output(n, 2);
                do
                {
                    fitness(n);
                    sort(n);
                    rng(n);
                    crossover(n);
                    fitness(n);
                    mutation(n);
                    antipushback(n);
                    fitness(n);
                    sort(n);
                    output(n, 3);
                    trigger = generation[0][2];
                    antipushback(n);
                    cleanup();
                    Sleep(10);
                } while (trigger < 99);
                cout << generation[0][0] << " " << generation [0][1]<<" "<<trigger;
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Возьмите новую точку равной старой и скорость роста будет минимальной (это если вы по модулю разность берете) - так что лучше изменить фитнес-функцию.

Comment: И да, я на stackoverflow совсем недавно, если пост/код нечитабельны, я что-то упустил - буду благодарен за конструктивную критику. Не знал даже как подступиться к такому вопросу.

Comment: @GreenDragon просто никаких идей, как ее иначе устроить.

Comment: Разбейте популяцию на 2 части и пусть одна ищет минимум, а вторая - максимум.

Comment: А код, после того как сделаете работоспособным, отправьте на [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @GreenDragon конкретно у этой функции нет глобальных минимума и максимума. И точка, в которой скорость изменения функции равна нулю всего одна 1;-2

Comment: Так  алгоритм и не может найти глобальный оптимум, только локальный, а если его нет - сойдется к граничной точке. А зачем вам привязываться к скорости изменения функции, это не градиент и ничего вам не даст.